# How can I run Flask app to be run on my site?

Tags: flask, deployment, web-development-server, serve

welcome everybody

this is my falsk app http://207.246.77.1:5000/ashrafapp

I uploaded it to my server and I want to run it on mys site https://www.ailottoexpert.com/ on the same server

How can I make it run on this link like this https://www.ailottoexpert.com/ashrafapp
So the port disappears from the website address>

Can someone help me, please?

whaen I open this link https://www.ailottoexpert.com/ashrafapp

it will show th condent of tha app on this page http://207.246.77.1:5000/ashrafapp